# What does "name of a man" mean?

Tags: meaning

Liu Kang tells Cole about his career at Wu Shi Academy:

> Liu Kang: I met Lord Raiden. Kung Lao and I have served together. Upon
> graduation, I was given a **name of a man**.

What does "name of a man" mean?

Source: [Mortal Kombat (2021) – Transcript](https://scrapsfromtheloft.com/2021/04/23/mortal-kombat-2021-film-transcript/).

Comment: Source please!  It probably means there is some tradition in the academy of receiving a new name when you graduate, you lose your name as a child and get your "man's name". In other words it is completely literal. but I don't know this unless because I don't know the context

Comment: @JamesK Looks like the source is [Mortal Kombat (2021) – Transcript](https://scrapsfromtheloft.com/2021/04/23/mortal-kombat-2021-film-transcript/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is literal, I suppose.

In the Mortal Kombat games, Liu Kang is found in a gutter, he is an orphan and nameless.  He trains at a martial arts academy, and I suppose he gets a name when he graduates, which is his man's name. "Liu Kang" is a name of a man.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it means a title. For example, it is frequent that in popular novels warriors are given the names of 'snake', 'wolf' etc. when they earned fame.